# Cannot use `throw` after or (||) operator

Tags: javascript

I couldn't find in a general internet search, nor by reading the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) why is not possible to use this code:

```
let a;
a || throw Error(`'a' is undefined or falsy`);
```

I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw`.

Does anyone know why is not possible to use this way to code a throw?

Comment: Could do `a || throwError(``'a' is undefined or falsy``); function throwError(e) {throw Error(e)}` - Here's an [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qqsbtuz3/1/) **EDIT:** Having a hell of a time trying to escape the ` but hopefully you get it.

Comment: Beautiful @Santi , I'll use something like that until proposal-throw-expressions pointed out by ellisbben becomes Stage 4 or land in Nodejs without flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `throw` keyword indicates a throw *statement*, meaning it must be a statement by itself.

The parts on the left and right part of the `||` operator can only be expressions, not statements.

See the ECMAScript grammar section on [Statement Semantics](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-statement-semantics)

Answer (score 2):

Code like `a || b` is an expression; it's code that ultimately evaluates to a value.

In present-day JavaScript, `throw` is a *statement*; code that may have side effects but does not have a value.  This may change in the future: cf. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions .